# Failed to build flutterfire_cli:flutterfire

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web, firebase-tools

I am trying to activate FlutterFireCLI in my project so I entered this command:

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

However I get the following error:

```
Failed to build flutterfire_cli:flutterfire:
AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/response.dart:13:8: 
Error: Error when reading 'AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http- 
0.13.4/lib/src/utils.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.
import 'utils.dart';
^AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http- 
0.13.4/lib/src/base_request.dart:15:8: Error: Error when reading 
'AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/utils.dart': The 
system cannot find the file specified.
```

To fix the error I added C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin to my Path in system variables environment. (but it does not work)
I have already installed firebase command line tools. [This is my pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOa1V.png)

Comment: `flutterfire_cli` is a CLI tool. Why did you add it to your pubspec file?

Comment: I was trying everything to make it work